# operator/ overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

For learning purposes I'm creating big integer class in C++. There are 2 files:

**big_int.h**

```
#ifndef BIG_INT_H
#define BIG_INT_H

#include 

class big_int
{
public:
    big_int(void);
    big_int(char*);
    big_int(QString);

    ~big_int();

    big_int operator+(big_int);
    big_int operator-(big_int);
    big_int operator*(big_int);
    big_int operator/(big_int);
};

#endif // BIG_INT_H
```

**big_int.cpp**

```
#include "big_int.h"

big_int::big_int()
{
}

big_int::big_int(QString str)
{
}

big_int::~big_int()
{
}

big_int operator+(big_int b)
{
    return big_int();
}

big_int operator-(big_int b)
{
    return big_int();
}

big_int operator*(big_int b)
{
    return big_int();
}

big_int operator/(big_int)
{
    return big_int();
}
```

Qt Creator returns: C:/Documents and Settings/Admin/My Documents/calculator_1_0/big_int.cpp:31: error: big_int operator/(big_int) must take exactly two arguments. But operator/ takes only 1 parameter. What`s wrong?

Comment: A few more hints on doing it the right way:  Define `operator+=` first, and define `operator+` in terms of that (create a copy of one addend and add the other to it).  You are going to want a copy constructor (`big_int::big_int(const &big_int)`).  Less importantly, you should normally accept and return const references (`const big_int & big_int::operator+=(const &big_int`), although that's more a performance thing, so you don't need to worry about that yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a typo, you forgot the class name :

```
big_int big_int::operator+(big_int b)
{
    return big_int();
}

big_int big_int::operator-(big_int b)
{
    return big_int();
}

big_int big_int::operator*(big_int b)
{
    return big_int();
}

big_int big_int::operator/(big_int)
{
    return big_int();
}
```

By the way, you should take contant references instead of values :

```
big_int big_int::operator/(const big_int& v)
{
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

specify the class name as suggested by @TheSamFrom1984.

OR
Provide operators which takes two parameters for `big_int`.

```
class big_int
{
public:
    big_int(void);
    big_int(char*);
    big_int(std::string);

    ~big_int();

    friend big_int operator+(big_int, big_int);
    friend big_int operator-(big_int, big_int);
    friend big_int operator*(big_int, big_int);
    friend big_int operator/(big_int, big_int);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It is usually better to declare operators taking two operands as free functions outside the class and to declare inside the class the corresponding `X=` version. For instance:

```
class big_int
{
public:
  big_int& operator += (const big_int& rhs);
};

big_int operator + (const big_int& lhs, const big_int& rhs);

big_int& big_int::operator += (const big_int& rhs)
{
    ...
    return *this;
}

big_int operator + (const big_int& lsh, const big_int& rhs)
{
    big_int rc(lhs);
    rc += rhs;
    return rc;
}
```

Comment: best practice indeed. Btw you can pass lsh by value, this way you don't have to copy it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the class for each of the functions.

So change:

```
big_int operator+(big_int b)
```

to:

```
big_int big_int::operator+(big_int b)
```

Otherwise you need to specify 2 parameters for operators that work on 2 values like +, *, /, ...

But since you put the declaration of all the operators inside your class I think you want my first suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to prepend the operator methods definitions with the class name qualifier. They should look like this:

`bigint bigint::operator/(big_int)

{
  //method body
}`

BTW, the arguments to your operators should be passed as references, not values for efficiency reasons.

Answer (score 0):

There are already enough explanations here on how to fix this,
but as a side note, it's good to understand why you got a compiler error only for the `/` operator.
The first three operators `+`, `-` and `*` are also unary operators that only take one argument, for example:

```
int x = 3;
int y = +x; // unary + operator
int z = -x; // unary - operator
int *p = &x;
int q = *p; // unary * operator
```

So even though the compiler didn't complain for those operators, it follows that even they would not work as you probably intended. So be careful ;)